# What is the common practice to handle relation between Activity and Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, orientation-changes, android-configchanges

I have the following situation

1. I spawn a long running user thread (`Thread`) from an `Activity`.
2. I press soft back button. So, the `Activity` was destroyed.
3. I launch the same `Activity` again. Note, the previous launched `Thread` is still running.

In order for me to prevent the `Activity` from launching another same `Thread` while the previous `Thread` is still running, here is what I am doing

- After I launch the `Thread`, I will store it into a static variable. So, next time when I try to launch a same thread, I will check against the liveness of previous thread through the static variable. **Is this a good practice? What is the best practice to overcome this?**

Note, the user thread is holding reference to the `Activity` which launched it. However, the `Activity` might destroyed when user press on soft back button. So, when I launch the new Activity again, the `thread` is not aware of that, and it is still referring to old `Activity`. So, when user thread try to access any members of the old `Activity`, crashes will happen as the `Activity` already being destroyed. **What is the best practice to overcome this?**

Comment: make a method for Thread that changes the reference to Activity

Why don't you use AsyncTask sir?

Comment: When I say user thread, it can be `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. Doesn't matter. Both will encounter the same problem.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK my initial answer was incorrect. I've updated it to reflect what really happens.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Haha. You make me suspect on my initial finding, and causes me to write the test code to confirm AysncTask will still running when Activity is destroyed. But when the time I finish writing test code, you already update your post :p

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK Yeah, sorry... I'm getting a little hasty with my SO answers recently. Answering questions wrong to begin with and then checking to see if I was actually correct in the first place haha. BTW, this topic is covered *extensively* in this [**thread**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/4dW4-KMUKJI) on the Android developers group. Dianne Hackborn, Romain Guy, and Mark Murphy are all names you can trust with the correct answers (the first two are Android framework developers and Mark Murphy is the StackOverflow god known as CommonsWare :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to overcome this is to use an `AsyncTask` instead. If the `Activity` is destroyed while the task is executing, the `AsyncTask` (and its underlying `Thread` that is performing the operation) will continue its execution until `doInBackground()` has completed. If the `Activity` is `null` by the time `onPostExecute` is called, you won't run into any `NullPointerException`s for the reasons stated in this **[blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html)**.

If you want to immediately cancel the task if the user "backs out" of the `Activity`, you can call `mTask.cancel()` on your `AsyncTask` in your `Activity`'s `onDestroy` method.

If you *don't* want to immediately cancel the task if the user "backs out" of the `Activity`, then your long-term operation doesn't sound like it is specific to any `Activity` instance. In this situation, it is often advised to use a `Service` instead.

Comment: OK. I read through https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java, I can pretty understand the workaround. The activity merely removing the Thread's reference to itself, when it is destroyed.

Comment: How about the workaround to overcome duplicated Thread? Is using static variable is good practice?

Comment: Note, I do not wish to cancel the task when I "back out" of the Activity. I wish the task will continue obey my command :)

Comment: You can use `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to transfer active objects across activity instances. `static` variables are generally *not* good practice to handle these sorts of things because they can cause memory leaks (see the [**blog post**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on the topic). If you wish your task to continue even after the `Activity` is destroyed, then I would use a `Service` instead. `AsyncTask`s and `Thread`s are usually specific to an `Activity`, whereas a `Service` can exist even when the application isnt running.

Comment: I think you may need to make correction - whereas a Service can exist even when the **activity** isnt running. (Not application. If I explicitly kill my application, its service will dead too)

Comment: Oops... yes, I was incorrect again. Actually what I meant to say was "it can exist even when the application isn't in the foreground", I think. Thanks for letting me know about that... I wish I could edit the comment :\